# csshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e) while spinning the docker with user

Tags: windows, docker

Issue :

Observing csshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e) while spinning the docker with user.

Docker image -> mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004-amd64

Issue :

Observing csshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e) while spinning the docker with user.

Docker image -> mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004-amd64

Error snippet :
PS C:\Users\user> docker run --rm -it --user  mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004-amd64
Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004-amd64' locally
2004-amd64: Pulling from windows/servercore
295f12394c4f: Already exists
24b98dd3fbc4: Already exists
Digest: sha256:1241480fc719b88dbe0f482806d4f67ab90e10752ddd56c014f9a801d3aac991
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004-amd64
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 4ca11ac50559a3b374cf1c77077930a86576984b5db4ea92dbb82452feb4f10a encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7F50FA40B: (caller: 00007FF7F50B5C8B) Exception(2) tid(390) 8007052E The user name or password is incorrect.
CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe","User":"swjenci","WorkingDirectory":"C:\","EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[43,120]}.

Could anyone please help how to solve above issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.